# Doubly periodic function and theta function

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if for any set $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$ executed $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = 0 $ then for any $\lambda_i \in\Lambda_\tau $ $$f(z)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \frac{\theta'(z-\lambda_i)}{\theta(z-\lambda_i)}$$ is doubly periodic function.
Where $\tau\in\mathbb{C}$, $Im(t) \ge0$, $\Lambda_\tau=\mathbb{C} / (\mathbb{Z}+\tau\mathbb{Z})$ and $\theta(z)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^me^{(m-\frac12)^2i\pi\tau}e^{(m-\frac12)i\pi z}$.

I can't understand why we need the condition that $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = 0 $. And is there  a quick solution for it? (Without just putting everything under the sum sign)

Comment: One needs $\sum\lambda_i=0$ since that is the sum of the residues of $f$ within a fundamental region, and those residues always sum to zero for any elliptic function.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Maybe it's a stupid question, but why this sum is the sum of residues of $f$?